# Probability of drawing duplicate balls

Tags: probability

Consider the following problem:

Suppose that there are $n_1$ balls of color $c_1$, $n_2$ balls of color $c_2$,..., $n_m$ balls of color $c_m$ in a bin. Suppose we draw $k$ balls from this bin at random. What is the probability that the $k$ balls contain at least 2 balls of the same color?

This is how I calculated the probability:
Clearly when $k > m$, there will always be balls of the same color.
For $k < m$, we start with
$\Pr[\text{Duplicate}] = 1 - \Pr[\text{All unique colors}]$.

Now essentially, for all the balls to have unique colors, 1 ball each must be drawn for some $k$ out of the $m$ colors. Suppose we consider a set $S \subseteq 2^{[m]}$ where $|S| = k$. The number of ways of drawing one ball each from of the colors $c_i, i \in S$ is $\prod_{i\in S}n_i$. We sum over all such sets $S$ and divide by $\binom{n_1 +...+n_m}{k}$ to get the probability of getting all unique colors.

$\therefore\Pr[\text{Duplicate}] = 1 - \frac{\sum_{S \in 2^{[m]}; |S| = k} \prod_{i \in S}n_i}{\binom{n_1 +...+n_m}{k}}$

Is this calculation correct?

If it is, can we upper bound the duplicate probability by say some function of $e$?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the correct calculation. I believe the probability is maximized when all of the colors of balls are equinumerous. So, if you take the average of the $n_i$'s, you should be able to get a pretty decent estimate for an upper bound. In the case where the $n_i$'s are equinumerous, the numerator would be: $$\dbinom{m}{k}\left(\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^m n_i}{m}\right)^k$$

Comment: Equinumerous would maximize probability of uniques right? So it would result in a lower bound for the duplicate probability.

Comment: Oh, right. So, minimize the probability of all of the balls being unique will maximize the probability of duplicates. You can do this by assuming that one color has $$n_{\text{max}} = \left(\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^m n_i \right) - m+1$$ of the balls, and each other color has exactly one ball. The number of ways to choose no duplicates is then: $$n_{\text{max}}\dbinom{m-1}{k-1} + \dbinom{m-1}{k}$$

Comment: Or, if you know $$n_{\text{max}} = \operatorname{max}(n_i)_{i=1}^m$$ then say color 1 has maximum, color 2 has maximum, etc. until all that is left is 1 ball per color.